# How many Consumers on a VertX EventBus Channel?

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I want to publish a message on a EventBus channel and receive a response from everyone who's listening to that channel. The thing is, how to I know everyone has already responded if I don't know how many responses to expect?

I assume I need to know how many consumers there are in order to know that I already got all responses or not.

Is there any way to know how many consumers are currently "listening" to a Vert.x EventBus address?

Answer (score 0):

EventBus works on a "best effort" basis, so even if you could track the number of subscribers, there is a chance that some of them would never return your message.

If you're still inclined to try it, there are a couple of ways I can thin of. None are really recommended, but I'll try to highlight the pros and cons anywya.

One is to get a reference to `handlerMap` inside `EventBusImpl` through reflection.
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/impl/EventBusImpl.java#L48

If you get it once, when your application starts, that should have much impact on the performance. Of course that will break at runtime if Vert.x team decides to as much as change the name of the field.

Another option is to use `vertx.sharedData()`, for example `getLocalMap()`. All consumers will add themselves to the map, and producer will check the map to figure out how many consumers are listening. The problem with that implementation:

1. Lots of logic to implement this
2. Unregistering consumers is hard (there's no guarantee that consumer will be able to unregister itself)